# MySQL - List of articles, with largest height

Tags: mysql

I have two tables. One contains articles with an `Article_ID`. The other contains `Image_URL`, `Article_ID`, `height` and `width` (multiple images per article). I would like to produce a list of individual articles, along with the `Image_URL` of the image with the largest `height` associated with that article. I currently have:

```
SELECT Image_URL, Article_Images.Article_ID, height, width
FROM Article_Images
INNER JOIN  `Articles` ON  `Articles`.Article_ID = Article_Images.Article_ID
GROUP BY Article_ID
ORDER BY height
```

But this doesn't appear to be giving me the largest `height` image of each

Sample Records:

**Articles**

Article_ID | Article_Name

---

1  'Welcome to London'

2  'Things to do in London'

---

**Article_Images**

Image_ID | Article_ID |  Image_URL  | height | width

---

1 | 1 | img1.jpg | 300 | 600

2 | 1 | img2.jpg | 200 | 200

3 | 2 | img12.jpg | 100 | 200

---

Comment: What is largest" image? Only height doesn't mean it's largest (compare `height=100 & width = 5` with `height=50 & width = 20`)

Comment: I would like the image with the largest `height` (refined question)

Comment: As you will presumably be listing the articles more frequently than you will be adding taller images, you should consider adding a field 'FeaturedImage_ID' to the Articles table, and populating this with the largest image ID. This would also allow you later on to set which image you use.

Comment: Where there are multiple images with the same height, which would you want to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT  a.*, b.*
FROM    Articles a
        INNER JOIN Article_Images b
            ON a.Article_ID = b.Article_ID
        INNER JOIN 
        (
            SELECT  Article_ID, MAX(height * width) Largest_Image
            FROM    Article_Images 
            GROUP   BY Article_ID
        ) c ON b.Article_ID = c.Article_ID
WHERE   (b.height * b.width) = c.Largest_Image
```

but this will lead to confusion as to `5x7 = 7x5`.

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/947190/1)

**Based on the largest height value,**

```
SELECT  a.*, b.*
FROM    Articles a
        INNER JOIN Article_Images b
            ON a.Article_ID = b.Article_ID
        INNER JOIN 
        (
            SELECT  Article_ID, MAX(height) height
            FROM    Article_Images 
            GROUP   BY Article_ID
        ) c ON b.Article_ID = c.Article_ID
            AND b.height = c.height
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/947190/2)

Comment: With this I am getting multiple occurences of each Article_ID

Comment: can you give sample records?

Comment: I am not getting any duplicate records based on your examples: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/947190/1

Comment: Where two images for an article have the same size, they will both be returned (b.height = c.height). Presumably the real data contains images that have the same size.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this funny. You started off asking for size, then amended to height. But before you clarified the requirements, we started getting complicated.

I now realise that all you needed to do to your version was to change the ORDER BY to read

`ORDER BY height DESC`.

By default ORDER BY is ASCending, so 100 would turn up before 900. Thus your code was a list of articles with shortest height.

But for the record, here is the fixed and simplified version of John Woo's approach I cobbled together.

```
SELECT  a.*, b.*
FROM    Articles a
        INNER JOIN 
        (
            SELECT  *
            FROM    Article_Images 
            GROUP   BY Article_ID
            ORDER BY height DESC
            LIMIT 1
        ) b
```

However, you will be better off pre-storing the preferred thumbnail ID in the articles table.

Comment: do you this works? how many records does your subquery return?

Comment: The subquery returns 1 record because of the `LIMIT 1`. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f6ce1/5/0

Comment: Do you know I've a funny feeling that all the OP needed was the `DESC` keyword...

Answer (score -1):

Did you try :

> SELECT Image_URL, Article_Images.Article_ID, max(height) 'height',
>   width
>
> FROM Articl_Images
>
> INNER JOIN  `Articles` ON  `Articles`.Article_ID =
>   Article_Images.Article_ID
>
> GROUP BY Article_ID, height

Comment: With this I am getting multiple occurences of each Article_ID